# Does a gerund imply a subject like imperatives?

Tags: gerunds, implication

Does a gerund imply a subject like imperatives, or does a gerund need to have a possessive pronoun?

> Play soccer! *( = you play soccer.)*
>
> Playing soccer is fun. *(= your playing soccer is fun?)*

Comment: Please give concrete contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Playing soccer is fun* the subject or agent of *playing* (the person performing the action of the verb) is not a particular person, it is a ***general statement***. *Playing* does imply an agent, surely, but not in the way that the way that the imperative does (*Play soccer with me!* - who? - You: one person or more than one. The subject is specific.)

In *your playing soccer is fun*, the agent is definitely specified, and that is *you*. It is true, ***your*** is a possessive pronoun:

> *We often put a noun or pronoun in front of a gerund* ***to show who or
> what is doing the action in the gerund***. This noun or pronoun is called
> the ***subject of the gerund***. *In formal writing, the subject of the
> gerund should be in the **possessive** form*:
>
> - ***Your*** *leaving* early was a wise decision.
> - We celebrated ***Gord’s** winning* the contest.
> - Natalie objected to ***my** borrowing* her hockey stick.
>
> Note: *In informal writing*, there is a trend toward dropping the
> possessive before a gerund. We often use a simple noun or an object
> pronoun instead:
>
> - We celebrated Gord winning the contest.
> - Natalie objected to me borrowing her hockey stick.
>   However, *in formal writing*, ***the use of the possessive form before a
>   gerund is still preferred***. Also, the possessive form may be important
>   for clarity. Consider the difference between the two examples below:
> - Jorge is in favour of ***the candidate being interviewed*** Friday. [Jorge likes the candidate who has an interview on Friday.]
> - Jorge is in favour of ***the candidate’s being interviewed*** Friday. [Jorge wants the interview to be on Friday.]

([Termiumplus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_p&page=90SDm90b7Xlw.html))